# Cannot install the nuget package

Tags: visual-studio

I try to restore the code from others work but always cannot restore the nuget package. What should I do?

[Capture Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsMiJ.png)

Comment: looks like the package may have been pulled?

Answer (score 0):

Is `Dejavu.Security` or any packages private package? If not:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Do you need to upgrade [nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)

Also, Your Package source is `nuget.org`. I had this issue and switch to 'all`. Weird, that worked.

Comment: Not sure is that the package-private. I need to check with the code owner. May I know how to switch to 'all'. I would like to have a try.

Comment: Yes. Under `Nuget Package Manager: AutoCE.API.Service`. Left of the cog wheel you see: `Package source: [nuget.org]` It is a select dropdown